# set a pandas datetime64 pandas dataframe column as a datetimeindex without the time component

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

After importing data from a HDF5 file the index for my stock data has disappeared.

One of the columns in my dataframe "Date" is a Datetime64. How do I convert this date column to a `datetimeindex` column but without the time parts at the end.

So that slicing the dataframe like this `data.ix["2016-01-01":"2016-02-06"]` works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, starting from a sample dataframe as:

```
               Date  x
0  2016-01-01 20:01  1
1  2016-01-02 20:02  2
```

you can do:

```
df = df.set_index(pd.DatetimeIndex(df['Date']).date)
```

which returns your `DatetimeIndex` only with the `date` part:

```
                        Date  x
2016-01-01  2016-01-01 20:01  1
2016-01-02  2016-01-02 20:02  2
```

Comment: Thans Fabio, this seems to work. Is it possible to set another field as the index as well as the date, and access them both, given that many fields of study may have lots of data readings with the same date? Say for example temperature - the station and then the date as the index. Or stocks: the stock name, and then the date?

Comment: Glad that helped. But please consider posting another question for another answer. Finally if my answer worked well for your purposes, consider accepting it to help other users with your same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use `set_index` to convert the column to an index. You do not need to trim the time part for the it to work.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'ts': pd.date_range('2015-12-20', periods=10, freq='12h'),
    'stuff': np.random.randn(10)
    })
print(df)

      stuff                  ts
0  0.942231 2015-12-20 00:00:00
1  1.229604 2015-12-20 12:00:00
2 -0.162319 2015-12-21 00:00:00
3 -0.142590 2015-12-21 12:00:00
4  1.057184 2015-12-22 00:00:00
5 -0.370927 2015-12-22 12:00:00
6 -0.358605 2015-12-23 00:00:00
7 -0.561857 2015-12-23 12:00:00
8 -0.020714 2015-12-24 00:00:00
9  0.552764 2015-12-24 12:00:00

print(df.set_index('ts').ix['2015-12-21':'2015-12-23'])

                        stuff
ts                           
2015-12-21 00:00:00 -0.162319
2015-12-21 12:00:00 -0.142590
2015-12-22 00:00:00  1.057184
2015-12-22 12:00:00 -0.370927
2015-12-23 00:00:00 -0.358605
2015-12-23 12:00:00 -0.561857
```